# How to change the images size when using knit to word in r-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am using a for loop to generate a lot of images to put into a word document.

To get them in i use the ! [Alt text] (/Users/Antonio/Documents/images/tufte.book.jpg) method.

This works well but regardless of what I do i am not able to make the image bigger (fill the entire page)

Any ideas on how to progress?

Comment: have you tried `![image](foo.jpg){width=15cm}`, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes

Comment: Yes it did not seem to work with Word, but switched to PDF and then it worked very well